# html in views/notifier doesn't see my model attribute. Error: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Greetings!
I'm new in Rails, and Rails 4, I'm learning it using the Beginning Rails 4, 3rd Edition. And, I'm having a problem to get an attribute when my mailer try to access it in html. This is my problem:

**NoMethodError in Articles#notify_friend**

Showing /home/alex/Documents/curso_rails4/blog/app/views/notifier/email_friend.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `title' for #< Array:0x007f4521586278> (I had to put the space in <  A to appear here.)

**Extracted source (around line #14):**

```
           </p>
            <p>
                Come check all the information about <strong><%= @article.title %></strong> at
                <%= article_url(@article, :host => "localhost:3000") %>
            </p>
        </body>
```

**Application trace:**
app/views/notifier/email_friend.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_notifier_email_friend_text_erb___902372559744089873_69967442421020'

app/mailers/notifier.rb:17:in `email_friend'

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:72:in `notify_friend'

**Articles Controller:**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # Applying filter here
  before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    # @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def notify_friend
    @article = Article.find([params[:id]])
    Notifier.email_friend(@article, params[:name], params[:email]).deliver
    redirect_to @article, :notice => "Successfully sent a message to your friend"
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :location, :excerpt, :body, :published_at, :category_ids => [])
    end
end
```

**Mailer Notifier**

```
class Notifier < ApplicationMailer
  def email_friend(article, sender_name, receiver_email)
    @article = article
    @sender_name = sender_name
    mail :to => receiver_email, :subject => "Interesting Article"
  end
end
```

**Email_friend.html.erb in views/notifier**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            One of your friends, <%= @sender_name %>, thinks you like an article we have written.
        </p>
        <p>
            Come check all the information about <strong><%= @article.title %></strong> at
            <%= article_url(@article, :host => "localhost:3000") %>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using an array here, which is suggesting you want an array of results:
`@article = Article.find([params[:id]])`

If you do `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` instead, you should be fine!

Comment: My problem was solved. Thank you so much! The book is right, I don't know how I ended up putting this [ ] on params[:id].

Comment: great!  please mark as the correct answer/up-vote if this fixed it for you.